# SQL/Snowflake How to count across columns?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to count the number of columns in a row that are true. For example:

| INDEX | COL 1 | COL 2 | COL 3 | # TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | false | true | 2 |
| 2 | false | false | false | 0 |
| 3 | true | true | true | 3 |

I know I could solve this using a case statement with a pascal's triangle number of conditions, but is there an easier or more scalable way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

[Explicit conversion](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-logical.html#id1) Boolean -> INT:

```
SELECT *, col1::INT + col2::INT + col3::INT AS num_of_true
FROM tab
```

Comment: I was actually looking for this everywhere. Neat!

Answer (score 2):

The CASE of Samuel's answer `CASE WHEN [COL 1]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` can be replace with an [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) `IFF("COL 1",1,0)`

thus

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IFF("COL 1",1,0) + IFF("COL 2",1,0) + IFF("COL 3",1,0) AS "# TRUE"
FROM table
```

You can loop across columns in a stored procedure, or use client side scripts in python/javascript/etc to build the SQL.

Comment: Thanks, helps make it nice and concise!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to automatically iterate through columns in SQL (in a sort of 'SUM columns 1-5' sort of way), so I believe you'd have to explicitly name each column.

You could create your calculated column above by doing something like

```
SELECT *,
(
CASE WHEN [COL 1]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN [COL 2]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN [COL 3]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS "# TRUE"
FROM [...]
```

Comment: Ah this is good enough for me, I can make a Liquid template for loop with the case statements and that will make it much easier to scale up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't care about how many columns you have - by leveraging `object_construct`:

```sql
with data as (
    select $1 id, $2 c1, $3 c2, $4 c3, $5 c4
    from values(1, true, false, true, true)
    , (2, true, true, false, false)
    , (3, true, true, true, true)
), transformed as (
    select object_construct(a.*) b
    from data a
)

select seq, count_if(value='true')
from transformed, table(flatten(b))
group by 1
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you choose object_construct over array_construct? I'd have thought the array would be a simpler object therefore faster?

Answer (score 0):

This might come in more handy if you have a lot of non-null columns.

```
select regexp_count(concat(col1,col2,col3),'true', 1, 'i') -- i is a case insensitive flag
```